# How should I unit test this module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, bdd

I have been doing Rails development for a short time now but have done pretty well picking it up fairly quickly. One area I've still been lost is with writing tests.

I understand how to write tests, but I never know what I should be testing for and has made it difficult for me to actually start writing my own tests.

I recently wrote a gem to use with an API for a project I'm working on and figured this would be the best time for me to write some tests. I'm still so lost on what I should be testing.

I was hoping if I posted one of my classes with a couple of the methods that someone might be able to give me some ideas on what I should be testing for.

The API I'm working with returns JSON objects so all of my methods are really just helpers to that make GET requests and return JSON back to the application I'm building. I'm using the HTTParty gem to make the get requests.

The first method just lists some information about a particular advertiser:

```
    module MyModule

    class User < MyObject

      # User
      # This will list information about a specific user
      # required parameter(s):
      #     user_id
      # example:
      #   MyModule.connect("Your API Key")
      #   MyModule::User.list(5)
      # returns:
      #   Returns a single result with the following properties:
      # {
      #    "user_name":"blah",
      #    "user_id":253,
      #    "last_login":"2011-03-01"
      # }   
         def list(user)
      MyModule.get("/users/#{user}")
         end
    end
   end
```

My initial guess is I would test to make sure this JSON object comes back with the correct properties but I'm not entirely sure.

Would I also need to test to make sure arguments being passed into the method are there or is that something I shouldn't worry about?

Comment: Check out the source code and tests for some other gems like [httparty](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty/tree/master/spec) (since you're using it). Also, rdoc/yardoc are really useful for end-developers, so I'd recommend using the right docstrings and syntax for those tools.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing should be checking the *behavior* of some object or method, not object composition. Even so, there are really only a couple things you can test here:

1. That your GET request succeeds (or not).
2. That you get back valid JSON (or not).
3. That your record isn't mangled.

You should probably be testing at a slightly higher level. For example, I'd test this user story:

```
Given a record with some reasonable fixture data,
When the record is successfully retrieved
Then your application does something useful with it.
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about testing is it's all up to you about how thorough you want to be. In an ideal world you would have a test for every single aspect of your application. Seeing as you're probably working on a side-project, and your time is better spent programming the application, I would think just basic flow testing would suit your needs.

Yes, checking for the correct JSON properties would be a good start.

You didn't mention what testing suite you're using -- I would recommend rspec if you didn't have anything in mind already.

Hope that helps,

Reagan

Comment: I'm actually using minitest for this. I wrote a really small test to make sure I have a version number so I could get used to how minitest works, but couldn't really decide what else to test. Because this is a gem I plan on publishing I would like to test as much as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I find it helps when I don't think of it as a test, but instead think of it as an example of how my class behaves. @CodeGnome's answer is pretty spot on. From reading the code and your description, you have one obviously valuable aspect of behavior: your class finds login information about advertising users. (Please excuse my lack of knowledge of Ruby and Rails-specific syntax, going to do the same as @CodeGnome but with a more specific example).

Your class "should retrieve the last logged in date of an advertising user". That looks like a description that matches its behaviour, and you can name your test method after that.

Now think about some particular examples. Does it ever retrieve different data depending on the user? What if the user hasn't logged in before? What if the user id is wrong? Will MyModule always be available, or is it perhaps unavailable if you lose your mobile connection? What will you do then? Is it the case that your class "should escalate connection errors"?

By thinking this way you'll find the different aspects of behaviour and different examples. Something like RSpec will help you to phrase those easily, or you could `just_use_underscored_test_names`.

If you don't *have* different aspects of behavior you probably have premature refactoring / optimisation, and too many layers of abstraction.

Just remember, you're looking at examples of how the class behaves and why it's valuable, so that you can document it and make it easy to understand. You're using that to  help refine the responsibilities of your class so that it stays maintainable. It's not actually about testing.